# Checking if a Variable exists without using v.get() in Dask Distributed Client

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

When using a Dask Distributed Client, I can easily get a variable like this:

```
v = Variable('myvar') 
v.get(timeout=5)
```

But if I do this on a none existing key:

```
v = Variable('doesntexist') 
v.get(timeout=5)
```

Gives me, after 5 seconds:

```
distributed.utils - ERROR -
tornado.gen.TimeoutError
```

Is it possible to check beforehand if a variable exists without relying on timeouts?

Regards,
Niklas

Comment: It's a valid question.  Currently I think that the answer is "no".

Comment: Would it be something you would consider merging if I could cook up a PR? (I'm not sure if I know enough about Dask to do it, but if)

Comment: Yes, I would consider that